# How to connect to another page after logging in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to to connect to another page after logging in HTML.
For example I have my login page when I submit my information (username, password) I have an action for my login and I want to go to another page when my Authentication is true.

I don't have acces of the code of the server, server using jps

Comment: What are you using on the server? Your tags don't say. Authentication is going to happen on the server, so it will handle the logic that chooses the response.

Comment: but what serverside language are you using to authenticate the user? tell that, for further help.

Comment: Would that be Asp.net MVC? ... because you used word *action*...

Comment: Based on his *other* questions I'm taking a wild guess: he's using **java/jsp**. But this question will get closed if he doesn't provide this info soon.

Comment: I don't have acces of the code of the server, server using jps

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/" />
```

or

```
<?php header( 'Location: http://example.com/' ) ; ?>
```

When you authenticate user

Comment: Who says he's using PHP? And what would your code do else than refresh existing page? Based on the word *action* in his question I suspect he's using Asp.net MVC.

Comment: If not use php then he can use meta refresh,to redirect to another page, not to refresh current page!

Comment: why i do redirection ..? when i log i lost my authetification page and i have the home page of the site i can't do redirection

Answer (score 0):

It depends what language you use in the backend.

If you do only javascript validation of the login, you should drop this logic and rewrite it using a proper backend language (php, .net, rails, or whatever), since it would be a **huge** security problem.

Example of redirection using Ruby on Rails:

```
redirect_to "yourpath"
```

using PHP:

```
header("Location:yourpath");
```

Comment: i don't have acces of the code of the server, server using jps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using form in jsp or html you can use the folowing code,

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="sec.jsp">
```

This will direct to `sec.jsp`. You can also use servlet mapping if you are using servlets.

Comment: why i do redirection ..? when i log i lost my authetification page and i have the home page of the site i can't do redirection